# Angular 6: Reactive Form's updateOn: 'submit' is not updating value after submitting

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I'm testing with Angular reactive form validation with `updateOn` parameter but it seems that even the simplest form is not working correctly when I pass `updateOn: 'submit'` (other values are working fine).

app.component.html:

```
<form novalidate (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type="text" [formControl]="form.get('test')">

  Value: {{ form.get('test').value }}

  <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  public form = new FormGroup({
    test: new FormControl('', { validators: [Validators.required], updateOn: 'submit'}),
  });

  public onSubmit(): void {
    console.log('Submitted:');
    console.log(this.form.value); // Got: Object { test: "" }
  }
}
```

Full and working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/67pmd

What I'm getting after clicking a button is empty field value (both in html and in console). But if I change/leave `updateOn` to default, then it's working fine. From what I see, value and validations should be updated only after submitting the form, but it seems that it doesn't? What I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten to bind your `formGroup` to your template. The `form` FormGroup is bound to the `<form>` element with the `formGroup` directive. (Source: [docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-1-creating-a-formgroup-instance))

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" novalidate (submit)="onSubmit()">
    <input type="text" [formControl]="form.get('test')">
    Value: {{ form.get('test').value }}
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

**Edit**:
The reason why other values like `blur` and `change` are working fine with `updateOn` is beacause `blur` and `change` are events fired based on your input while submit is an event that's fired when the form itself is submitted. To know when the form is submitted, Angular needs to know what the `formGroup` is.

Comment: Yes, that solved the issue. But how come then value is being updated correctly if I use `updateOn: 'blur'` (or `change`) but not on `submit`?

Comment: @GytisTenovimas - It is working on ````submit````. All I did was add the ````formGroup```` to the html in your example (which uses ````updateOn: 'submit'````) and I see data in the console and in the template.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I asked my question incorrectly. What I meant is why `blur` and `change` work without `[formGroup]=“form”` but `submit` doesn’t? Shouldn’t they all require `[formGroup]=“form”`?

Comment: @GytisTenovimas - This is beacause ````blur```` and ````change```` are events on your input while ````submit```` is an event that's fired when the form itself is submitted. To know when the form is submitted, Angular needs to know what the ````formGroup```` is.

Answer (score 0):

If formcontrol associated with FormGroup Then you should wrap your from element with FormGroup directive, and use FormControlName directive to bind the input element

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <form [formGroup]="form" novalidate (submit)="onSubmit()">
        <input type="text" formControlName="test">
        <br>Value: {{ form.get('test').value }}
        <br><button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Example:https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-8pt02?fontsize=14

Comment: I think you forgot to update the example correctly since it's not working as intended, but your answer helps to solve my issue. Appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `[formGroup]` to bind the value of your form by the `onSubmit()` method of your `component.ts` file and `formControlName` to bind the values of fields of the form.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-form-controls-example',
  templateUrl: './custom-form-controls-example.component.html'
})
export class CustomFormControlsExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      mySwitch: [true]
    });
  }

  submit() {
    console.log(`Value: ${this.myForm.controls.mySwitch.value}`);
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Reactive Forms</h3>
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <label for="switch-2">Switch 2</label>
  <app-switch formControlName="mySwitch" id="switch-2"></app-switch>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```